# Cannot convert return expression of type '[Favorite.Type]' to return type '[Favorite]'

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, swift4.2

I want to make a general function for getting Elements from UserDefaults that are conforming to the NSObject and NSCoding Protocol. But when I want to use that function I get this error

```
    func getFavorites() -> [Favorite] {
        return get(type: Favorite, forKey: UD_FAVORITES)
    }
```

> Cannot convert return expression of type '[Favorite.Type]' to return type '[Favorite]'

That's my UserDefaults Extension:

```
    func get<T>(type: T, forKey key: String) -> [T] {
        if let data = self.object(forKey: key) as? Data {
            do {
                let tData = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as! [T]
                return tData
            } catch {
                debugPrint(error)
                return [T]()
            }
        } else {
            print("EMPTY \(key)")
            return [T]()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `type` must be `T.Type`

```
func get<T>(type: T.Type, forKey key: String) -> [T] { ...
```

and you have to call it

```
return get(type: Favorite.self, forKey: UD_FAVORITES)
```

---

Actually you don't need the parameter, this is Swift, the compiler can infer the type (specified by the return type `[Favorite]`)

```
func get<T>(valueForKey key: String) -> [T] {
```

and

```
return get(valueForKey: UD_FAVORITES)
```

---

And there is

```
if let data = self.data(forKey: key) {
```

Comment: Thank you :) I didn't knew that before.